# APA7 Class: How to modify the section title of appendices

Tags: titlesec, appendix, apa7

I'm using the APA 7 document class.

And it formats the section titles of appendices Like this:

### Anhang A

### Appendix title

I need to format it like this:

### Anhang A: Appendix title

I've been browsing the code of the class (as a seldom-programmer), but cannot figure out, how those titles get formatted.
Because changing it using titlesec doesn't move a thing...

Thank you for your kind help :)

EDIT: Thanks for informing me about the MWE. This makes total sense!

This is the basic structure:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, donotrepeattitle, oneside, man]{apa7}

\begin{document}
\listofappendices
\appendix
\section{First Appendix}
\end{document}
```

I tried to modify the title with titlesec. Didn't work.

In the class of the source code, the appendix section gets formatted like this:

```latex
 \long\def\section##1{%
     \makeatletter%
     \def\@currentlabelname{##1}%
     \makeatother%
% ...
     \refstepcounter{appendix}
                      
 
      
\centerline{\normalfont\normalsize\textbf\appendixname\ifoneappendix\else~\textbf\theappendix\fi}
\centerline{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries##1}\par%
%...
                      \makeatother%
                  }%
```

So I solved it like this:

```latex
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\listofappendices
\appendix

\makeatletter
%...
\renewcommand\section[1]{
    \newpage
%...
    \centerline{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\appendixname\ \@Alph\thesection:\ #1}\par%
}
\makeatother

\section{First appendix}
\end{document}
```

And now it works!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please do not post a link to some project on the internet. Instead, try to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). The reason is that this site is intended to serve as a Q&A for other users in the future and the access to the linked project is likely to be restricted soon or the link might be broken due to some other reasons. Apart from that, creating a MWE often helps to single out the reason for the unwanted behaviour much quicker.

Comment: I've taken a look at the OP's driver file. Since it loads lots of secondary files, there's almost nothing anyone but the OP him/herself to do with this driver file. Request to OP: Please provide some relevant sample code that can be compiled even when one doesn't have access to `settings/macros.tex`, `settings/packages.tex`, `bib.bib`, `contents/Titelseite.tex`, etc.

Comment: It's great that you've managed to solve your problem. Instead of adding it to the question, it's perfectly fine to add an answer explaining your solution. That way the question ends up with an answer and can help others more easily.